# Спиннер при долгом тапе сам прокручивается к текущему выбранному элементу

Tags: android

Совершенно непонятно почему спиннер себя так ведет. Обратите внимание на полосу прокрутки. Причем что Spinner, что AppCompatSpinner ведут себя одинаково.

[image: Пример проблемы]

@zTrap, @kizoso, я даже обнаружил любопытных код внутрях SDK на который у меня подозрения. Внутри класса android.widget.ListPopupWindow обнаружил вот такой слушатель:

```
private class PopupTouchInterceptor implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        final int action = event.getAction();
        final int x = (int) event.getX();
        final int y = (int) event.getY();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                mPopup != null && mPopup.isShowing() &&
                (x >= 0 && x < mPopup.getWidth() && y >= 0 && y < mPopup.getHeight())) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mResizePopupRunnable, EXPAND_LIST_TIMEOUT);
        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mResizePopupRunnable);
        }
        return false;
    }
}

private class ResizePopupRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        if (mDropDownList != null && mDropDownList.isAttachedToWindow()
                && mDropDownList.getCount() > mDropDownList.getChildCount()
                && mDropDownList.getChildCount() <= mListItemExpandMaximum) {
            mPopup.setInputMethodMode(PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NOT_NEEDED);
            show();
        }
    }
}
```

Как раз очень похоже на то что происходит, если количество элементов в спиннере больше чем помещается на экран - вызывается метод show если не убрать палец за четверть секунды (EXPAND_LIST_TIMEOUT). Правда мне тогда совершенно непонятно почему и как оно в других проектах работает...

Comment: Где тестирование проводите ? Имею ввиду эмулятор. Или что то в коде может быть

Comment: Эмуляторы, реальные устройства, на одном проекте повторяется на любых экранах, даже если просто спиннер добавить с набором строк из array-string и никаких слушателей не вешать, на другом проекте не повторяется. Повторяется только с 6 или 7 андроида.

Comment: Без кода ничего не понять однозначно

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос [mcve] без него невозможно вам помочь

Comment: @kizoso, @zTrap, беда в том что весь код заключается в
`<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth=100dp
            android:entries="@array/spinner_data"
/>
`

А воспроизвести не удается даже на другом проекте. Хотя на любых активити и фрагментах текущего проекта воспроизводится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем выяснил с чем это связано было, на версии androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01 работает нормально, на более свежих есть такой баг... Странно что не заметил когда проверял на другом проекте что там другая версия appcompat была.